# Highcharts logarithmic chart not displaying series on webpage

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to display some data on my web page using a highcharts columnrange chart with a logarithmic axis. While it works with some data, in some cases it draws the chart without displaying the series.

In JSfiddle the chart is displayed correctly. Here is some sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/3rcRh/1/

```
$(function () {
var mychart;
var ser1=[{"name":"Series1","data":
    [{"groupName":"Group1","low":1.0,"high":16.0,"x":27},{"groupName":"Group2","low":16.0,"high":17.0,"x":27},{"groupName":"Group3","low":17.0,"high":18.0,"x":27}] }];
 mychart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Selected Data'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Groups'
    },

    xAxis: {

        title: {
            text: 'Number of ELements'
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        title: {
            text: 'Value Range'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: [true]

    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {             

                        alert('clicked');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columnrange: {

        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },

    series: ser1

});
```

});

However, even here when I choose "Share full screen result" I get the same problem, the data isn't displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/3rcRh/1/embedded/result/

When I download the chart as image or pdf from the chart context menu, the downloaded file contains the correct image of the chart.

I have included all the necessary scripts on my web page but I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Your jsFiddle code page and jsFiddle Share page both show the series for me. What browser are you getting this issue in. I am on FF.

Comment: Tried it on FF, Chrome and IE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2067) - thanks!

You can workaround this:

- change from `columnrange` to `column`
- in data change from `high` to `y`
- set min for `yAxis: 1`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3rcRh/2/